# Ruby on Rails: one check_box for several submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I need to have one check_box for several purposes. 
For example: I have a list of files. User can choose some of them to be deleted or analysed.

I have the following code but it accepts only one submit_tag "Delete selected".

```
<% if @files%>    
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_files_path, method: :delete do %>
<%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
  <% @files.each do |file| %>
    <% if (arraydb.file=="no") %>
        <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td><%= file.name %></p>       

    <% else %>      

    <div class="my_profile_info">     
    <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td> <%= file.name %></p>        

    <td class="Info">
    <a href="<%=file.info%>" target ="_blank" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">Info</a>  
    </td>  

     </div>

    <% end %>
  <%end%>

<%end%> 
<%else%>

<%end%>
```

I would like to have submit_tag  "Analyse"  as well.
I tried something like this but of course it did not work.

```
 <% if @files%>    
    <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_files_path,analyse_multiple_files_path method: :delete,method:post do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Analyse" %>
      <% @files.each do |file| %>
        <% if (arraydb.file=="no") %>
            <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td><%= file.name %></p>       

        <% else %>
....
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :files do
      collection do             
        delete 'destroy_multiple'      
      end
    end
```

controller:

```
 def destroy_multiple          

      @files = File.find(params[:files])    
      @files.each do |item|          
          item.destroy
       end    

  end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
    <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_files_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Delete selected", :name => 'delete' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Analyse", :name => 'analyse' %>
```

controller:

```
if params[:commit] == 'Delete selected'
  # delete things
elsif params[:commit] == 'Analyse'
  # analyse things
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :files do
      collection do             
        get :destroy_multiple      
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed have multiple submit buttons, you just have to give them names:

```
<%= submit_tag "Delete selected", :name => 'delete' %>
<%= submit_tag "Analyse", :name => 'analyse' %>
```

You can then check what the `commit` param contains in the controller and act accordingly:

```
if params[:commit] == 'delete'
  # delete things
elsif params[:commit] == 'analyse'
  # analyse things
end
```

The rest of the form will be submitted as usual.

Comment: If I pass a variable :name, then I have to catch it in a controller as well with params[:name], don't I? I have tried your variant and the variant with :name instead of :commit. It doesn't delete anything. Can it be connected with delete 'destroy multiple' in my routes? I updated my question